# How to close the JQuery Dialog Box from the child page

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using JQuery and C#.

I am opening a JQuery Modal Dialog on the click of login link. Then I submit the complete form and form action is changed to my /login.aspx page, for a 15 seconds I am showing ajax processing image and on login.aspx page I validate the username and password entered by user. There can be two scenario

1) User enters the valid username and password, in this case I am again redirecting back to same page from where the login link was clicked after validating on my /login.aspx page, this functionality is working fine as my current page is reloaded again.

2) however when user enters wrong username and password, I keep user on /login.aspx page (Please note I don't redirect back to the page from where user has clicked the login link). Now Issue is that when user enter wrong username and password then /login.aspx comes, however if user in between clicks the browser back button then my Dialog box is shown open as I have set timeout for 15 secs. I want to close the dailog box once user enters the wrong username and password.

Below is the Jquery code where I am opening the dialog box.

```
 $('#skywardsLogin').dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        width: 450,
                        modal: true,
                        title: $('.LoginpopupHeaderText').text()
                    });
```

And here I am trying to submit the form and changing the form action and also I am given timeout for 15 secs for showing the ajax processing image.

```
$("#aspnetForm").attr("action", "http://localhost:8080/english/include/aspx/Login.aspx");
$("#aspnetForm").submit();
$('#divSuccessLogin').show();
// Wait for 15 seconds 
setTimeout(closeDialog, 15000);
```

CloseDailog code is given below.

```
        function closeDialog()
        {
            $('#skywardsLogin').dialog("close"); 
}
```

I am struggling to close my dailog box as there is timeout for 15 secs to show the ajax processing image. please suggest

Comment: What's the problem?  What are you struggling with?  Is closeDialog getting called or not?

Comment: All is working fine If I am one the same page dialog box is closing properly, however when user enters the wrong username and password then according to the code written in my login.aspx code it will reside to login.aspx page else it will be redirected back to the same page from where the login link was clicked, my concerns is that I am using 15sec timeout for showing the ajax processing image, and if user has entered wrong values and if he clicks browser back button my dialog box still showing ajax processing image as the timeout is given for 15sec and afte 15sec it closes.

Comment: Its a bit confusing. Why do you use the timer? Why not when clicking on login just show the dialog (without timer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Gidon it's a bit confusing. But let's see if I understand you correctly, let's do it step by step.

1. User comes to a page, let's say index.aspx.
2. User clicks a link that opens a dialog (using `$().dialog()`)
3. In the new dialog the user put's in their username/password.
4. When pressing a submit button you change en action of aspnetForm and submit the form.
5. If the information is incorrect the user is still on login.aspx.
6. User uses the browser's back-button
7. What happens?

It's the last part I don't quite understand. If the user clicks on the back button doesn't they end up on index.aspx?

Also why the timer? There are no ajax calls? `$("#aspnetForm").submit();` submits the form as a normal html form or are you using something to override jQuery's standard `.submit()`

In any case if you want to invoke something after an ajax call is completed don't use a timer use:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#skywardsLogin').dialog("close"); 
});
```

Also it would be good if you could provide a link to the solution.

Are I'm on the right track?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will just correct something in your steps. 4) # When pressing a submit button you change the action of aspnetForm and submit the form and now my processing image comes for timeout 10 secs and in between login.aspx comes in figure where after validating the username and password it again reload the index.aspx page if it is valid page, however if incorrect user still on login.aspx page, and then if user clicks on browser back button it still shows my processing image.